I am learning squid since while and configured ldap authentication now i want to ask that can i authenticate squid user from keycloak
I want authenticate user of squid proxy server with the keycloak. But after searching i have not find any acl and method which can solve my problem.
i have tried with php script but not successful yet.
When i am executing my php script squid gives error deactivate.

Please have a look at [ask] and provide all details, relevant code and error messages inside the question - How to create a [mre]
